# Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Just wanted to know if anybody has come close to solving the Goldbach's conjecture problem ?

I have seen some videos on youtube where interesting geometric patterns have been found.

Anybody here made any progress on this problem ?

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 7):

There is a succinct and accessible account of the latest on Goldbach and the twin prime conjecture by Chris Linton in his October 2013 Editorial for *Mathematics Today*, published by the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications (IMA) here:

http://www.ima.org.uk/_db/_documents/MT_Editorial_Oct13.pdf

Comment: Just in case that link goes down, here's the bit talking about the closest result so far: "and in 1973 Chen Jingrun proved that all sufficiently large even numbers can be written as the sum of a prime and a number with at most two prime factors"